# hashmap with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap

First I try make intent with array from hashmap
intent is just one class and works

```
        try{

        JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("result");

        for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("tempat", "" + e.getString("place"));
            map.put("kode", "" + e.getString("code"));
            map.put("jarak", "Jarak: " +  e.getString("distance"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "tempat", "jarak" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(KalkulasiJson.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            Intent i = new Intent(KalkulasiJson.this, Details.class);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

}
```

---

and then I wanna make intent with many class and specific value from array

```
        try{

        JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("result");

        for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("tempat", "" + e.getString("place"));
            map.put("kode", "" + e.getString("code"));
            map.put("jarak", "Jarak: " +  e.getString("distance"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "tempat", "jarak", "kode"  }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_kode });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(KalkulasiJson.this, "ID '" + o.get("kode") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            TextView theCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_kode);
            String Codefix = theCode.getText().toString();

    if(Codefix=="kode001")
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(KalkulasiJson.this, Menu1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if(Codefix=="kode005")
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(KalkulasiJson.this, Menu5.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if(Codefix=="kode003")
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(KalkulasiJson.this, Menu3.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if(Codefix=="kode089")
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(KalkulasiJson.this, Menu89.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


        }
    });

}
```

only script toast is working, the intent is not affected

Comment: replace == with the .equals() function Codefix.equals("kode089")

Comment: its work , but.. when I click list number 1 the toast show ID kode001 was clicked, and Menu1.activity opened and then when I click list number 2 the toast show ID kode005 was clicked, and Menu1.activity opened It should be open Menu5.activity. any idea??

Comment: this is findViewById(R.id.item_kode); a listview item

Comment: yes, I get value Codefix from R.id.item_kode
but the intent always open menu1.activity

Comment: what is mylist? and show Adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(Codefix.equals("kode001"))...
```

Comment: its work , but..

when I click list number 1 the toast show ID kode001 was clicked, and Menu1.activity opened

and then when I click list number 2  the toast show ID kode005 was clicked, and Menu1.activity opened
It should be open Menu5.activity